# A lot of OpenNMS process

Tags: ubuntu, opennms

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.4 and when I start openNMS using this command:

```
service opennms start:
```

I can see a lot of process like this:

```
ps -ef | grep opennms
oot     13699     1 14 11:58 pts/1    00:00:42 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/opennms/lib/endorsed -Dopennms.home=/usr/share/opennms -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=18980 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Xmx1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -jar /usr/share/opennms/lib/opennms_bootstrap.jar start
postgres 13829  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53749) idle                                                                             
postgres 13830  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53750) idle                                                                             
postgres 13831  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53751) idle                                                                             
postgres 13834  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53752) idle                                                                             
postgres 13835  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53753) idle                                                                             
postgres 13838  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53754) idle                                                                             
postgres 13839  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53755) idle                                                                             
postgres 13841  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53756) idle                                                                             
postgres 13843  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53757) idle                                                                             
postgres 13845  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53758) idle                                                                             
postgres 13847  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53759) idle                                                                             
postgres 13849  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53760) idle                                                                             
postgres 13852  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53761) idle                                                                             
postgres 13854  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53762) idle                                                                             
postgres 13856  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53763) idle                                                                             
postgres 13858  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53764) idle                                                                             
postgres 13860  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53765) idle                                                                             
postgres 13862  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53766) idle                                                                             
postgres 13863  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53767) idle                                                                             
postgres 13865  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53768) idle                                                                             
postgres 13867  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53769) idle                                                                             
postgres 13869  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53770) idle                                                                             
postgres 13872  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53771) idle                                                                             
postgres 13874  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53772) idle                                                                             
postgres 13875  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53773) idle                                                                             
postgres 13878  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53774) idle                                                                             
postgres 13880  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53775) idle                                                                             
postgres 13881  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53776) idle                                                                             
postgres 13884  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53777) idle                                                                             
postgres 13886  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53778) idle                                                                             
postgres 13887  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53779) idle                                                                             
postgres 13890  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53780) idle                                                                             
postgres 13892  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53781) idle                                                                             
postgres 13894  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53782) idle                                                                             
postgres 13896  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53783) idle                                                                             
postgres 13898  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53784) idle                                                                             
postgres 13900  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53785) idle                                                                             
postgres 13901  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53786) idle                                                                             
postgres 13904  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53787) idle                                                                             
postgres 13906  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53788) idle                                                                             
postgres 13908  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53789) idle                                                                             
postgres 13910  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53790) idle                                                                             
postgres 13913  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53791) idle                                                                             
postgres 13914  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53792) idle                                                                             
postgres 13916  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53793) idle                                                                             
postgres 13917  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53794) idle                                                                             
postgres 13919  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53795) idle                                                                             
postgres 13922  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53796) idle                                                                             
postgres 13923  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53797) idle                                                                             
postgres 13925  9217  0 11:58 ?        00:00:00 postgres: opennms opennms 127.0.0.1(53798) idle
```

I wonder why I have a lot of process, are they harmless? How can I avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1):

This was explained in your [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/388322/many-postgresql-process-how-to-handle-them). Why would you think this is a problem given that you know that [OpenNMS depends on PostgreSQL](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/QuickStart#Configure_Your_Database)?

[Many Postgresql process. how to handle them?](https://serverfault.com/questions/388322/many-postgresql-process-how-to-handle-them)

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing are `postgres` processes, not `opennms` processes.  You can tweak the Postgres setup if you want--to reduce the number of processes--but there's also a lot of shared memory which makes the memory usage seem much higher than it is.  So unless you are experiencing reduced performance or other issues, I would say its not a problem.